# bridging table between many tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it a good idea to have a bridging table between many tables? I am trying to model many to many relationships between similar tables which hold data from different data sources.

For example, I have a few tables with similar information. 5 tables only for this example, but there could be more in real and each table could have millions of rows.

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR,
    domain VARCHAR,
    address VARCHAR
);
CREATE TABLE table_b (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR,
    domain VARCHAR,
    address VARCHAR,
    phone INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE table_c (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR,
    domain VARCHAR,
    twitter_url VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE table_d (
...
);

CREATE TABLE table_e (
...
);
```

Would it be a good idea to have a bridge table like the following, or is there a better way to model many to many relationships between many tables?

The purpose of the bridging table is to store a mapping within and between each of these tables.

```
CREATE TABLE bridge_table(
    a_id INTEGER,
    b_id INTEGER,
    c_id INTEGER,
    d_id INTEGER,
    e_id INTEGER,

    CONSTRAINT a_fkey FOREIGN KEY(a_id) REFERENCES table_a(id),
    CONSTRAINT b_fkey FOREIGN KEY(b_id) REFERENCES table_b(id),
    CONSTRAINT c_fkey FOREIGN KEY(c_id) REFERENCES table_c(id),
    CONSTRAINT d_fkey FOREIGN KEY(d_id) REFERENCES table_d(id),
    CONSTRAINT e_fkey FOREIGN KEY(e_id) REFERENCES table_e(id),
);
```

Comment: In these kind of questions the answer is always: "It depends on your needs". I mean if you have kind of a 'main' table, it might be better to add foreign keys to that table instead of creating a new table for this since having another table means more space in the memory and one more table to maintain. It's always a trade-off, are you able to sacrifice more resources to get more diverse database structure?

Comment: If you have those foreign key definitions, it does not make sense to duplicate the `name`and `domain`fields.

Comment: @clamp - think of table_a to table_e as the source data, which needs to be de duped via the bridge table

Comment: @VishalMalik . . . It is a good idea if such a bridge table correctly models your entities.  It is a bad idea if it does not.